# UITextView Font size set programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I want my `UITextView` font size to fill the width of the view.

So if I have the text:

> "I wish I \n
>   knew what \n
>   I was doing"

I would hope it would expand to be a good size for the width of the device.

`UILabel`s have `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`
but if I make a separate label for each line then the font sizes will be different because the strings are different lengths.

How do I pick the right size programmatically?

Comment: You'll have to calculate the needed font size so the text meets the desired width.

Comment: I may be wrong, being only young in The Force; but isn't Attributed Text meant to deal with these very issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
extension UITextView {
    func increaseFontSize () {
        self.font =  UIFont(name: self.font.fontName, size: self.frame.size.height / 4)!
    }
}
```

This extension will set font size of `textView` according to your `textView's` height.

And you can use it this way:

```
textV.increaseFontSize()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was accepted. Shouldn't the calculation be based on the text in the text view, in addition to the text view's width? I thought the idea was to size the font so the text filled the text view's width.